# How can i show alert message through Html.Telric.upload control using jQuery when form is submitted by a function?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, upload, telerik

I am using mvc3 application.

i am using `Html.Telric.upload()` control and through this i want to show alert message that "no file is uploded" on form submit like when form is submit then it calls the `ValidateSubmission` function for all the validations.

```
<input type="button" value="SUBMIT" onclick="ValidateSubmission('add');" />
```

in jquery function `ValidateSubmission` how will i check that files are uploaded or not using Telric upload control.

If anyone provide the solution then it would be appreciable.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[This link](http://www.telerik.com/community/code-library/aspnet-mvc/upload/upload-client-side-validation.aspx) contains a sample project which shows how you can validate that at least one file has been selected/uploaded. This works for both asynchronous (default) and synchronous modes with the upload component. If you take a look at that code it should help you figure out how to go about your validation.